# How do I use Create-React-App interactively without Typescript?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, next.js, command-line-interface

- Ubuntu 20.04 (running on WSL 2)
- Node 16.17.0

I run the following command to create my app.

`npx create-next-app ninjalist`

It presents me with the following prompt.

`Would you like to use TypeScript with this project? … No / Yes`

CLI will not accept any input when I type yes/no. All it will accept is the return key which seems to default to Yes. How do I get it to accept a no?

I had success running the command non-interactively.But I would like to know what I'm missing.This might be a broader CLI thing that I am just totally ignorant about.

`npx create-next-app ninjalist --js --eslint`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to navigate the options with the arrow keys on your keyboard :) If you click the left arrow or right arrow, you should see that the underlined option changes. If that doesn't work, maybe try a different terminal.